# Can I drive from the Netherlands to Copenhagen without taking a ferry?

Tags: germany, driving, ferries, denmark

I'd like to know if it's possible to drive to Copenhagen using only car, meaning no ferry from Puttgarden to Rødby. I'm asking this because the ferry costs around 200 euros, and if I can drive around it then I'd rather do that.

As you can see in this image, it says I need to go via ferry (*veerboot*):

[image: ferry]

but if I drag the route over the land, it doesn't say that anymore:

[image: noferry]

but I need to pay money to go across the border. (If anyone knows around how much that is, that would be helpful too!)

If Google Maps is right, then why would people pay 200 euros to get across by ferry if they can spend 20 minutes more and skip the ferry?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Most people didn't think to click OPTIONS and select Avoid Ferries. The route you are asking about would appear instantly if you do this.

Note that on this route there is a [€34 one way toll](http://www.storebaelt.dk/english/toll-charges) for crossing the [Storebælt bridge](http://www.storebaelt.dk/english). (There are also return tolls for evenings, weekends and bank holidays.) This route is also about 140km longer than the route using the ferry, so you use additional fuel.

[The ferry web site](http://www.scandlines.com/tickets-und-tarife/tickets-and-prices/puttgarden-rodby.aspx) shows prices starting at €39, but these appear to be available only if you book well in advance, with prices becoming much higher later or on the day. This isn't compatible with a long distance road trip where you can't really predict your arrival time at the ferry. I suggest you take the land route and enjoy the bridge crossing.

Comment: I'm going to guess confusion of Euro with Danish Crown. 1 Euro = 7.6 DKK.

Comment: I have this for example https://i.gyazo.com/7ad2f8eb29760ca10eb93f4e6b993be3.png it says 186 euros. I have no idea how it gets so high. I guess thats my bad for not doing enough research then.

Comment: or this one https://i.gyazo.com/40c031565c900186f01dba0d8878d86f.png but this is one way. If you take the way back too, it is around 190. Because normal economy isnt available untill 21-2.

Comment: Aha, it looks like demand pricing! You must book earlier to get the lowest prices. I suggest you save your euros for the bridge toll :)

Comment: Yes, ithought so Michael. Thank you for answering. Ill go drive across the bridge then!

Comment: Does your 140km difference already take into account that your *car* travels 0 km while on the ferry, or is it the total difference in route length?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Your car travels 0 meters while on the ferry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, just say you wanna pitstop/go through the city "odense". It's the "central" city of the island in the middle "fyn".

There is only one paid bridge from "Fyn/odense" to "sjælland/københavn". It costs approx. 67€

Comment: That's the return price. One way is €34.